# Error in action for react redux not working

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I need to call an action function in redux, but not working

My code:

```
export const loginUser = (email: string, senha: string) => {
  console.log(email);
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch(loginUserStart());
      console.log('Teste');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
};
```

First console.log have return in screen, but console in return not working.
All code inside return, not result

Comment: Resolved, I need to have redux-thunk

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has solved this problem and it's not reproducible.